# How can I write this condition in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I write this condition in PHP?

```
if $x=0 then $y=$z
```

Comment: why not write appropriate title of the question?this has been discussed several times.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
<?php
if ($x == 0) {
    $y = $z;
}
```

You can also provide a default value for `$y` like this:

```
<?php
if ($x == 0) {
    $y = $z; // Set y = z
} else {
    $y = 0; // Set default value for y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
$y = ($x == 0 ? $z : {null, or whatever else $y should equal});
```